# What CloudWatch events will trigger a Glue job to start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a series of Glue jobs that depend on data in S3 that gets dumped there by a separate DMS job. I have that DMS job running from a cron job on an EC2 instance.
All of Glue's trigger functionality seems to concern itself with just Glue jobs. Is there a CloudWatch event that will trigger a Glue job? I know I can get CloudWatch to recognize when DMS finishes successfully and if I can get a Glue job to trigger from CloudWatch I'll be able to string it all together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently CloudWatch doesn't support AWS Glue job as a [target for Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_PutTargets.html).

Alternatively you can [setup a Rule to trigger Lambda on the DMS event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) which will [start an ETL job by calling Glue API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-calling.html)